# Fans/lights switches can be turned on/off from different locations

Tags: electrical

I have three ceiling fans (with lights). Each fan has a faceplate with three on/off switches on the wall.  It would all be very simple if either turned off or on either the light or the fan - but it appears that the three fans are interconnected with each other by the third switch. How do I know which switch needs to be in the on position and which in the off position to get each fan/light to work?

Comment: Can you turn the circuit off and post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: So... There's 3 fans, and 9 total switches? A diagram or some photos might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So....the third switch of each set of switches controls what? Does it shut off all power to all three fan/lights?

I am thinking someone wired a 3way circuit to control all power from any location.

So to answer your question, one of the three switches in each location will control the power to all three units. If they used logic it should the the same switch in each location and it will not be marked on/off on the handle of the switch, since it is a 3way or 4way switch. Then each of the other switches will control the fan or light on its respective unit. These will be marked on/off on the handle of the switch.

Give that a try.